# Print an array inside of object in Java

Tags: java, object

I have a class and a constructor that fills an array with numbers and it sort it:

```
public BinaryArray(int size){

    data = new int[size];
    for(int i:data){
        data[i] = 10 + generator.nextInt(90);
    }        
    Arrays.sort( data );
}
```

then in my other class where I have the main I want to print the array:

```
BinaryArray searchArray = new BinaryArray( 15 ); //  create the Object

    for(BinaryArray i:searchArray){
        System.out.println( searchArray[i] );
    }
```

but its wrong.. I also code this but it prints sth else..

```
BinaryArray searchArray = new BinaryArray( 15 );
System.out.println( searchArray );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a getter method in the class where you have the array:

```
public int[] getArray() {
    return data;
}
```

And then use that method in your main method:

```
BinaryArray searchArray = new BinaryArray(15);
for (int i : searchArray.getArray()) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

**Edit**

Your constructor has a major bug:

```
for(int i:data){
    data[i] = 10 + generator.nextInt(90);
}
```

`i` will always be set to `0` because every field in this array was initiliazed with `0`. Therefore only the first index will be set with the random number. The others will keep their 0.

To fix that, use this loop instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  data[i] = 10 + generator.nextInt(90);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

1 - Create a getter for the array.

```
public int[] getArray() {
 return data;
}
```

2 - Display the array

```
BinaryArray searchArray = new BinaryArray( 15 ); // create the Object

for(int i:searchArray.getArray()){
    System.out.println( i );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, in the above code, i always equals 0, you have to iterate with an index

```
data = new int[size];
for(int i:data){
    data[i] = 10 + generator.nextInt(90);
}
```

You can implement `toString` in `BinaryArray`

```
public class BinaryArray
{
    private int[] data;

    public BinaryArray(int size)
    {
        data = new int[size];
        for(int i: = 0; i < size; i++){
            data[i] = 10 + generator.nextInt(90);
        }        
        Arrays.sort( data );
    }

   public String toString()
   {
       for (int i : data)
       {
            System.out.println(i);
       }
   }
}
```

And then

```
BinaryArray searchArray = new BinaryArray( 15 );
System.out.println( searchArray );
```